# How do you disable magnific popup on mobile devices?

Tags: magnific-popup

I would like to disable the popup on mobile devices. I found this code in the documentation but I don't understand where to place the code for it to work.

```
disableOn: function() {
          if( $(window).width() < 600 ) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me.
https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#disableon

You can set `disableOn:` propery for magnificPopup, defining conditions when not to open popup.

```
$(el).magnificPopup({
        disableOn: function() {
            if( $(window).width() < 600 ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    })
```